# page transition with ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys I've recently seen a website : http://soulland.com/
I'm wondering how they did the page transition that is :
when click a link the page fades out then waits for page to load then fades in entirely
how they have done this ?
I have a code running on my website project but it didn't give the same result:

```
<script>
    var speed = 800;
    $('body').hide();
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
          $('a[href]').click(function(event) {
              var url = $(this).attr('href');
              if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('JavaScript:') == 0) return;
              event.preventDefault();
              $('body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                  window.location = url;
              });
          });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I want two methods : 
first case : fade in / out section of page
second case : fade in / out entire page

Comment: I'm not going to click on random links while at work, but does it actually change to a new page or is it an SPA?  Can't you view the source on the page?

Comment: click on store .
you will see the effect

Comment: mmm sry I didn't view the source but how can this work !!

Answer (score 0):

One way how to that is to make your web page opacity equals to 0 by default and change it to 1 when whole page has been loaded. Change of opacity together with css transitions should do the trick:

Your styles:

```
body {
   opacity : 0;
   transition : all ease 1s;
}

body.loaded {
   opacity : 1;
}
```

Your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass('loaded');

  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('loaded');
  });
});
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTfMsopJiTK1a5QYthnu?p=preview)**

Comment: how to check if whole page have been loaded ?
$(document).ready() .. ??
how to go to get the url from the link ,, how to get to another page with fade in ,,etc

Comment: Yes, you can check it by using ready event of jquery. Also you don't need to add any hacks to your links, the only thing you'll need to do is to include these styles/scripts on your page. I've updated demo and you can check how it works with two pages.

Comment: actually I made a mistake in the question:
and changed the question to :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611715/page-transition-with-jquery-ajax